# How to change default runlevel

Tags: system, startup

How to change default runlevel prior to installing NVIDIA driver? I know I have to press Ctrl+Alt+F1 on logon screen.

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/inittab/rc-sysinit.conf`

Answer (score 1):

You can install the driver's in runlevel 3.

```
CTRL+ALT+F2
$ sudo init 3
```

Or if you want to stay at your runlevel but only want to clip off X:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
```